# How to differentiate between scroll event and long press event?

Tags: javascript, mobile, dom-events

**Problem :**

```
SomeDomElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function preventLongPress(event) {
              
                  if (event.touches.length >=1) event.preventDefault();
                }, false);
```

If I use :  `if (event.touches.length >=1) event.preventDefault();` then this prevents long press event but also disables the scroll event.

There is no `touchmove` or `touchend` events for long press.

**What I desired :**

prevent long press but don't prevent scrolling

N**ote :** I am using vanilla Javascript only , no jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
    detectTap = false;
});
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(){
    detectTap = true;
});
document.addEventListener("touchend", function(){
    if(detectTap)
        alert("scrolled"); /* here add whatever functionality you wants */
    else 
        alert("long pressed"); /* here add whatever functionality you wants */
});
```